# How to pass java literals from python dictionary

Tags: java, python, json

I am trying to give rest call to java API using python.

Java API needs JSON input with java literals like `{a:null,b:true,c:false}`,

While parsing the JSON from python it is not allowing to do so because python needs null,true and false to be inside double quotes like *"null","true","false"*.

what is the solution?

Comment: Java is different from Javascript.

Comment: JSON is string. Its JS object in string. You will have to pare data.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

The JSON syntax expects values to be quoted.
It means that the problem comes from the java JSON api.
What API do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

while passing json to java api from python replace null with None ,true with True and false with False. It will work